# Write functions that take a non empty array of doubles and its length as arguments and returns :

Tags: c, arrays, function, boolean, structure

Write functions that take a non empty array of doubles and its length as arguments and returns :
a) the sum of the items 
b)the index of the maximum value 
c) a boolean which indicates if the numbers are in strictly increasing order

Comment: You didn't show anny effort and expect us to do your work?

Comment: Cynthia, bienvenida a Stack Overflow. Aquí respondemos preguntas puntuales, y dudas técnicas. Esto parece un ejercicio dado en clase. Nos estás pidiendo que hagamos tu tarea! Para recibir ayuda en este sitio, te recomiendo primero atacar el problema, y venir cuando tengas un impedimento puntual. Que quede claro que lo intentaste, y que no estamos haciendo tu trabajo por vos :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Answer (score 2):

Clue 1:
You can return a structure with 3 variables inside, something like this:

```
struct Resu{
    double sum;
    int max;
    bool order;
};
```

Clue 2:

```
Resu homework(double d[],int l){
..
.. your code must be here
..
}
```

Clue 3:

```
Resu homework(double d[],int l){
     Resu result;
..
.. your magic must be here
..
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @chux: Edited... Thanks!